# generate a pattern dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, design-patterns

I wish to make a dataframe as below.
and I wish to have 3 parameter x,y,z,

x is number of "a"
(number of "b" = column number, at first column, number of "b" is 1),

y is number of column,

z is number of row,

if x=2, y=5, z=16, then
[image]

```
this is my code, I can't solve this problem. 
1. how to fill the empty space.
2. how to rename the column ([x]to[column number])
I need help.

library(dplyr)


x <- 2
z <- 16
w <- 5

df <- data.frame(matrix("", nrow = z, ncol = w))

for (col in 1:w) {
  a_count <- x
  b_count <- col
  
  df[1:a_count, col] <- "a"
  df[(a_count + 1):(a_count + b_count), col] <- "b"
}

print(df)


  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   a  a  a  a  a
2   a  a  a  a  a
3   b  b  b  b  b
4      b  b  b  b
5         b  b  b
6            b  b
7               b
8                
9                
10               
11               
12               
13               
14               
15               
16
```

Answer (score 4):

A little function using `rep` inside `lapply` should do what you need here

```r
make_df <- function(x, y, z) {
  lapply(seq(y), function(n) {
    rep(c(rep("a", x), rep("b", n)), len = z) }) |>
    as.data.frame() |>
    setNames(paste0(x, "to", seq(y)))
}
```

Testing:

```
make_df(x = 2, y = 5, z = 16)
#>    2to1 2to2 2to3 2to4 2to5
#> 1     a    a    a    a    a
#> 2     a    a    a    a    a
#> 3     b    b    b    b    b
#> 4     a    b    b    b    b
#> 5     a    a    b    b    b
#> 6     b    a    a    b    b
#> 7     a    b    a    a    b
#> 8     a    b    b    a    a
#> 9     b    a    b    b    a
#> 10    a    a    b    b    b
#> 11    a    b    a    b    b
#> 12    b    b    a    b    b
#> 13    a    a    b    a    b
#> 14    a    a    b    a    b
#> 15    b    b    b    b    a
#> 16    a    b    a    b    a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Map` with `rep`

```
f <- function(x, y, z) {
    list2DF(
        setNames(
            Map(
                \(u, v) rep(c(rep("a", u), rep("b", v)), len = z),
                x,
                seq_len(y)
            ),
            paste0(x, "to", seq_len(y))
        )
    )
}
```

## output

```
> x <- 2

> y <- 5

> z <- 16

> f(x, y, z)
   2to1 2to2 2to3 2to4 2to5
1     a    a    a    a    a
2     a    a    a    a    a
3     b    b    b    b    b
4     a    b    b    b    b
5     a    a    b    b    b
6     b    a    a    b    b
7     a    b    a    a    b
8     a    b    b    a    a
9     b    a    b    b    a
10    a    a    b    b    b
11    a    b    a    b    b
12    b    b    a    b    b
13    a    a    b    a    b
14    a    a    b    a    b
15    b    b    b    b    a
16    a    b    a    b    a
```